# Angular EventEmitter subscriptions on subscription on a pipe dissappear after OnInit

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscription, angular-event-emitter

The Flow:

When a user likes another users post, the flow sends a notification through ChatHub. In case the OP is online, he recevies a notification that one of his posts has been liked.
The flow gets the postLike from backend, based on the notification, and should emit that post to the notificationmenu (the subscriber on the eventemitter).

the Event

```
this._hubConnection.on('PostLikeNotification', (postLikeNotification:any) => { 
    this.Service.getPostLike(postLikeNotification.postId, postLikeNotification.likedByUserId).subscribe(postLike =>{
        this.likedPost.emit(postLike);
      });
});
```

the Subscriber

```
this.Service.likedPost.subscribe(postLike => {
   if (postLike.postAuthorId == this.user.id){
         this.newPostLikes.push(postLike);
   }
});
```

The Problem:

OnInit I can see the notificationsmenu registering the subscription and adding it to Observers of the EventEmitter.
By the time it needs to Emit there are no subscribers/observers on eventEmmitter likedPost

So the event works like it should, it gets a notification, gets the postLike based on the notification and emits the postLike.
The subscription in correct OnInit, but has dissappeared by the time there is a value emitted.

The strange things:

When I debug step for step, subscription on the eventemitter is NOT removed and all goes well.
So I thought: Ohyes, its a subscription (of the eventemitter) on a subscription (of the service getting the postLike) on a pipe(map()) from the backend, and you can't subscribe to a subscription and expect all to be well.

So I tried

```
this.Service.getPostLike(postId, likedByUserId).subscribe(postLike =>{
    this.emitLikedPost(postLike);        
  });
```

with

```
emitLikedPost(postLike: any){
  this.likedPost.emit(postLike); 
}
```

And it still doesn't work.

Other things I tried include making the getPostLike() async, also no success there.

I think I  need either a switchMap or a mergeMap but am not sure which one and where I would add this. None of the examples on the official documentation are of this structure, and I don't know whether I need to 'maintain more than one subscription' for this flow.

I'm also considering sending the postLike through a Hub but would require quite some refactoring, so would like to explore the options in the current setup first.

All input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing the problem. This would also reduce the amount of text needed to explain the problem and you might just figure out what's wrong yourself when creating the reproducer

Comment: @MikeS. So what can I add so you understand the problem?

Comment: What if you use a BehaviorSubject instead of the eventEmitter?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi It was a good idea! Unfortunately, when I use BehaviorSubject, the subscription is not registered onInit. (I'm using BehaviourSubject for other flows and there I get it to work.) With the regular eventEmitter, subscriptions are added to eventEmitter.observers onInit (in debug mode) but when I fire the flow without breakpoints, the thing is dead

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the service's constructor (for purpose only) and one in the component, which one of those is being called first?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I was subscribing in a component , not a service, hence it didn't subscribe... this is me, laughing at old noob-me ;) thanks for help tho!